# Error: The Bumblebee daemon has not been started

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I saw that there are some posts about that, but any of them I can find the solution to fix mine. I have a Sony Vaio vpcz11c5e with Ubuntu 11.10.

Graphics:

- Nvidia GeForce GT 330M
- Intel graphics

I followed [BumbleBee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) on wiki.ubuntu.com but when I run: `sudo optirun glxspheres` I get:

```
[ 3399.786675] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[ 3399.786711] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

I tried to follow all the other posts but I could not get with the error.
I am kind of Ubuntu new player, so if you need to know the kernel version or something like this, specify the command so we could go faster please.

Error message on

```
more  /var/log/syslog | grep bumblebeed

Mar  4 20:50:39 xinxi-VPCZ11C5E bumblebeed[4187]: Module bbswitch could not be loaded (timeout?)
Mar  4 20:50:39 xinxi-VPCZ11C5E bumblebeed[4187]: No switching method available. The dedicated card will always be on.
Mar  4 20:50:39 xinxi-VPCZ11C5E bumblebeed[4187]: Invalid configuration: no driver configured.
```

Comment: `sudo glxspheres` is wrong, did you mean `optirun glxspheres`? Anyway, check your /var/log/syslog file for error messages.

Comment: what kind of error message i have to look for?

Comment: did you upgrade your system with xorg-edgers ppa, recently? if so, try to purge it and reinstall bumblebee, nvidia-current and bumblebee-nvidia packages.

Comment: lines related to "bumblebeed"

Comment: I did a clean install of the 12.10 and proceed to install directly the Bumblebee. I havent even install any Nvidia driver before. Just follow the steps ok the wiki Bumblebee.
I added he information of the syslog
The power consumption says 24 W

Comment: @Xinxi88 Have you installed linux-headers-generic already? (make sure that your system is fully up-to-date, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`)

Comment: Everything is upgraded and the linux-headers-generic installed as well

Comment: nobody? :). Or maybe know any website that I can look for? thanks